# why is the .loc() function returning an empty Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

when I excute
`basic_data.loc[2:61, 'v_00']`
it return
`Series([], Name: v_00, dtype: float64)`

Why?

I wonder why I got empty series.

Comment: Try `basic_data.loc[61:2]`?

Answer (score 2):

`2:61` will slice the rows (by **position**) that are between the row index 2 and the row index 61, which are none. It will not consider the **values** between the integer 2 and 61.

I believe you want [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
basic_data.loc[basic_data.index.to_series().between(2, 61), 'v_00']

# or
basic_data.loc[(basic_data.index >= 2) & (basic_data.index <= 61), 'v_00']
```

Or first sort your index:

```
basic_data = basic_data.sort_index()
basic_data.loc[2:61, 'v_00']
```

Comment: Or `basic_data.loc[61:2, 'v_00']` is index is really, as it seems, in descending order.

Comment: @chrslg yes fair point ;)

Comment: Wow!~~~ It works. Thank you so moch. But why I excute the code `basic_data.iloc[2 : 61, 1]` can get what I want?

Comment: Because `iloc` works by **position**, not values. If would slice even if you don't have have 2/61 in the index.